Spatial autocorrelation between two sets of point data
I have 2 sets of point data (coordinates). The first related to crime at sea and the second related to fishing villages. I want to determine if there I spatial correlation between the points at sea and the fishing villages.
I am not sure how to approach this problem. I am trying to solve this in either QGIS or R.

You should probably pick either QGIS or R, or your question may get closed as to broad

How you want to do it? Just identify the nearest village to each crime site? Or how?

You really need to formally define what the autocorrelation means, mathematically and statistically, and then use statistics to solve. Can you define a null hypothesis (ie what you might consider "No correlation") and that should guide you to the alternative hypothesis which there may be code in R to test or you can sometimes do it with a Monte-carlo approach.
